# Store string from textbox on buttonclick to use that variable on page reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

How do i store textbox input on buttonclick, so that the page reload can use these values to recreate some of its content? 
I've tried with using viewState but it allways just says null on page_load when using breakpoints.

Button click:

```
protected void LoadLifeLineBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["lifelineID"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    ViewState["phaseid"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
    this.Page_Load();
}
```

And heres my page_load

```
int lifelineid;
int phaseid;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hideAndShow();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lifelineid = 22222;
        phaseid = 1;
        FillFaseTable(PhaseMainTable, phaseid, lifelineid);
        PhasePanel.CssClass = "panel col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 Phase1BackgroundColor";
    }
    else if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (ViewState["lifelineid"] != null) 
        {
            lifelineid = (int)ViewState["lifelineid"];
        }
        if (ViewState["phaseid"] != null) 
        {
            phaseid = (int)ViewState["phaseid"];
        }
        FillFaseTable(PhaseMainTable, phaseid, lifelineid);
        PhasePanel.CssClass = "panel col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 Phase1BackgroundColor";
    }
}
```

Comment: previously had this.Page_load(null,null) as it requires something.
The reason i used this.Page_load in LoadLifeLineBtn is because i got to set the values for viewstate, but at than point page_load had allready finished its run (since it does it before buttonclick)

Comment: Refactor the code inside the `else if(IsPostBack)` block into a method, then call that method instead of calling `this.Page_Load()`. Actually you need just the last two lines.

Comment: YES! that worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your button is wired up to this event

```
<asp:Button ID="LoadLifeLineBtn" runat="server" OnClick="LoadLifeLineBtn_Click"></asp:Button>
```

You should be able to change this around a bit to get a smoother flow in the code.

```
protected void LoadLifeLineBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hideAndShow();

    int lifelineID = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    int phaseid = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);

    FillFaseTable(PhaseMainTable, phaseid, lifelineid);
    PhasePanel.CssClass = "panel col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 Phase1BackgroundColor";
}
```

Now reorganize your `Page_Load` event to handle when the page initially loads

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hideAndShow();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lifelineid = 22222;
        phaseid = 1;
        FillFaseTable(PhaseMainTable, phaseid, lifelineid);
        PhasePanel.CssClass = "panel col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 Phase1BackgroundColor";
    }
}
```

The reason is that when the `LoadLifeLineBtn_Click` fires, you can do what you need at that point and not call the `Page_Load` event directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a second answer to help explain a little bit of what is going on in your code when you click the `LoadLifeLineBtn` button.

When you click `LoadLifeLineBtn`, it fires the `LoadLifeLineBtn_Click` event which will create a *PostBack* and the values entered into `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` will already be part of the `ViewState`.

In your code you can change it to this, and it should continue on as you intend without manually setting the `ViewState`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int lifelineid;
    int phaseid;

    hideAndShow();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lifelineid = 22222;
        phaseid = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        lifelineID = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        phaseid = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
    }

    FillFaseTable(PhaseMainTable, phaseid, lifelineid);
    PhasePanel.CssClass = "panel col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 Phase1BackgroundColor";
}
```